# Videofile sharing issue with Xamarin.Essentials

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I'm using the next code:

```
try
{
   await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
   {
      Title = filename,
      File = new ShareFile(filename),
      PresentationSourceBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
   });
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

and now I'm trying to share different file types. ASCII and binary files could be shared without any problems, but when I'm trying to share videofile, e.g. `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxx/Library/Caches/app_2022_06_14_17_58_13.mp4`, Dropbox shows a message `Couldn't load file. Sorry, an error occured`, others destinations such as `Save to files` doesn't show error but file is not written.

I tried to specify file media type with `File = new ShareFile(filename, "video/mp4"),` or to use library asset file like `assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=xxxxx&ext=mp4`, but this doesn't help.

I'm using Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.3, iOS version is 15.5

What could be a reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you declared the keys in your `Info.plist` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios)?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, yes, both keys are declared

Answer (score 1):

You need set the `PresentationSourceBounds` correctly.In my scenario, I put the `mp4` file in the Resources folder.Please see my sample code for your reference:

**Using Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0, iOS version is 15.5**

```
        
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fn = "sample-5s.mp4";

            var bounds = ((Button)sender).Bounds;
            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
            {
                Title = "My title",
                File = new ShareFile(fn, "video/mp4"),
                PresentationSourceBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)bounds.X, (int)bounds.Y, (int)bounds.Width, (int)bounds.Height)
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work too. But you gave me an idea that problem could be in the source folder (I can't use `Resources ` folder because video writes in the app). So I changed source folder from Caches to Documents and now it works!